# Heroku buildpack for Dart: Pushing app to Heroku

Tags: heroku, dart, push, buildpack

I am using this "Heroku buildpack for Dart" from the following Github repository: https://github.com/igrigorik/heroku-buildpack-dartam .

I followed the set of commands to deploy the HTTP server built with Dart to Heroku and once I try to push the app to Heroku (git push heroku master) I receive the following error:

```
    remote:   End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either 
    remote:   this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of 
    remote:   a multi-part archive.  In the latter case the central 
    remote:   directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last 
    remote:   disk(s) of this archive.
    remote: unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of dart-
    remote:         sdk.zip or dart-sdk.zip.zip, and cannot find dart-
    remote:         sdk.zip.ZIP, period.
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Dart app.
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:  
    remote: !   Push rejected to testdartapp.
    remote: 
    To https://git.heroku.com/testdartapp.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 
    'https://git.heroku.com/testdartapp.git'
```

I am attaching a screenshot of my terminal output: [Pushing app to Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCks0.png)

Any advice is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like the download of the Dart SDK zip file is ending prematurely or the download is being corrupted.